# Change text according to active <li> using jquery

Tags: html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to change the text of the anchor dropdown tag based on the active `<li>` value of its children. The stack I'm using is Bootstrap 3 and Jquery 3.2

For example, if this was the current active li tag:

```
 <li>
            <a href="#apresentacao" data-toggle="tab">
             <h1 class="mobile-tab-text">Apresentação</h1>
            </a>
          </li>
```

The content of the code below should be 'apresentacao'

```
 <a class="dropdown-toggle tab-ativa-mobile" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
    Apresentacao
  </a>
```

This is the complete dropdown code:

```
 <li class="dropdown visible-xs-block">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle tab-ativa-mobile" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
        selected title
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="collapsed">
          <li>
            <a href="#apresentacao" data-toggle="tab">
             <h1 class="mobile-tab-text">Apresentação</h1>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#professores" data-toggle="tab">
              <h1 class="mobile-tab-text">Apresentação</h1>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#tab5" data-toggle="tab">Tab5</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
```

I've tried this so far, but with no success:

```
 $('.tab-ativa-mobile').text(()=>{
  var tabMobile = $('li.active > a > h1.mobile-tab-text').text();
  return 'ss' + tabMobile;
 }
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use onclick event so whenever `li` gets clicked just get the `.mobile-tab-text` value and set same to your `tab-ativa-mobile` using `.text()`.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
//li clicked
$(".dropdown-menu li").on("click", function() {
  $('.tab-ativa-mobile').text($(this).find("h1.mobile-tab-text").text()) //set text 
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="dropdown visible-xs-block">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle tab-ativa-mobile" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
        selected title
      </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="collapsed">
      <li>
        <a href="#apresentacao" data-toggle="tab">
          <h1 class="mobile-tab-text">Apresentação1</h1>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#professores" data-toggle="tab">
          <h1 class="mobile-tab-text">Apresentação2</h1>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#tab5" data-toggle="tab">
          <h1 class="mobile-tab-text">tab5</h1>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hey, Swati! Thank you very much, you helped me a lot!!!

Comment: Glad i help  You can set this answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark :).

Answer (score 0):

For the first load, i don't what the first title you want to show. So i assumption your first menu be title.
And the second, i don't know what the event to add `active` class in the dropdown-menu so i assumption if someone click it.

```
<script>$(document).ready(function(){
  var a = $('ul.dropdown-menu li:first-child a');
  func(a);
  $(document).on('click', 'ul.dropdown-menu li a', function(){
    func($(this));
  });
});
function func(a){
  $('ul.dropdown-menu li').removeClass('active');
  a.addClass('active');
  $('.tab-ativa-mobile').text(a.children('h1').text());
}
</script>
```

If you want change the anchor title of the dropdown button by the scrolling, you can use event `scroll`
Hope you enjoy.